# SQL Select from multiple tables where Name contains query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with the following columns

```
TableA
Name Description .....
TableB
Name Description ....
TableC
Name Description ....
```

I want to do a Select query where I select 
The Name and Description from these three tables If the name contains my query.

Comment: Can you post an example of your desired results?

Comment: I have 3 different sql select queries, is there a way to do all these in one combines query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Description
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Name LIKE '%YourSearch%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Description
    FROM TableB
    WHERE Name LIKE '%YourSearch%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Description
    FROM TableC
    WHERE Name LIKE '%YourSearch%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Youre description is a little unclear, but it sounds like you want a union

```
SELECT  Name, Description FROM TableA where Name = @myNameFilter
  UNION ALL
SELECT  Name, Description FROM TableB where Name = @myNameFilter
  UNION ALL
SELECT  Name, Description FROM TableC where Name = @myNameFilter
```

It's not clear if you want duplicates or not (could be UNION instead of UNION ALL).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are asking for.

```
select * from tableA where name = 'Foo'
Union
select * from tableB where name = 'Foo'
Union
select * from tableC where name = 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all Name, Description columns from tables tableA, tableB and tableC whose name contain a certain word, it should be something like this:

```
select Name, Description from TableA where Name like concat('%', word, '%')
UNION
select Name, Description from TableB where Name like concat('%', word, '%')
UNION
select Name, Description from TableC where Name like concat('%', word, '%')
```